# RESTEasy Response vs. W3C spec

Tags: http, entity, httpresponse, w3c, resteasy

How does the RESTEasy `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` and `javax.ws.rs.core.ResponseBuilder` related to the [w3c HTTP (section 6.1)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) response spec?

W2C defines the HTTP response as:

```
   Response      = Status-Line               ; Section 6.1
                   *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                    | response-header        ; Section 6.2
                    | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                   CRLF
                   [ message-body ]          ; Section 7.2
```

and RESTEasy defines these methods (among others) on the ResponseBuilder object:

- status
- header
- type
- entity

The **`header`** method I understand allows you to enter custom headers into the response. **`status`** populates the `Status-Code` header and **`type`**, the `Content-Type` header.

However, I don't understand the role of **`entity`** does it populate the entity-header or the message-body or what?? Also does the **`header`** method allow you to populate standard headers?? And if I am returning a message describing the reason for the error should this be in the entity-header, message-body or should I populate the `Reason-Phrase` header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entity() populates the message-body.
The header() allows you to populate any response header (standard op proprietary).
I'm not aware of a possibility to set the reason phrase (which is not a header).